# Cufon font text not aligning property in Windows 8

Tags: wordpress, windows-8, cufon

I am having an issue with Cufon fonts on my Wordpress site.  The top of the font is being cut off.  I am using the MySiteMyWay theme called "Method".  The issue is visible from a Windows 8 PC using Firefox, IE, or Chrome.  I don't have enough reputation yet to post the screenshot, but you can view it at   https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZunp.png

Thanks

Comment: probably a fixed-height container, and your font's default `em` height is bigger than the container.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to see this on other windows operating systems. I'm using vista and have something similar. Im my case I found this http://kaptinlin.com/support/discussion/comment/13545#Comment_13545 worked. It did however, mess with the overall line height.